# jquery ajax 'post' call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, wcf, json

I am new to jQuery and Ajax, and am having trouble with a 'post'.

I am using a jQuery Ajax 'post' call to save data to a DB. When I attempt to save the data, it passes null to my C# method. The jQuery looks like this:

```
function saveInfo(id) {
        var userID = id; 
        var userEmail = $('.userEmail').val();
        var userName  = $('.userName').val();

        var dataJSON = {"userID": userID, "userEmail": userEmail, "userName": userName};

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../../Services/AjaxServices.svc/SaveUser',
                data:JSON.stringify(dataJSON),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json'
            });
        return false;
    }`
```

.userEmail and .userName are class references to input fields. The C# code looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://testUsePage.com")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]                                                                        

public class AjaxServices
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat           = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public void SaveUser(User user)
    {
        //code here handles save
    }
}
```

I have a breakpoint set inside the 'SaveUser' method, and the User object passed is always null. Thanks!

EDIT: I switched the 'POST' to 'GET' in both the ajax call and WebInvoke attribute. Passing one parameter ( {"UserID": UserID} ) to the method with the signature ( public void SaveUser(string UserID) ) reaches the breakpoint, and passes the UserID with no exception. Switching it back to a post immediately causes an internal server error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should send your user data in this way:

{ user : { userID : 1, ... } }

since you are using wrappedrequest. First element in your json should be your parametername.

The rest of your code seems ok. You should use stringify.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to use json for something so small.  try this

```
function saveInfo(id) {
    var userID = id; 
    var userEmail = $('.userEmail').val();
    var userName  = $('.userName').val();
        $.ajax({type: 'POST',
            url: '../../Services/AjaxServices.svc/SaveUser/?userID='+userID+"&userEmail="+userEmail+"&userName="+userName,
        });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned in the initial post, the specified elements were only used for brevity. My actual object takes 52 parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't setting RequestFormat property of the WebInvoke attribute to json.

Also in the $.ajax call send data: dataJSON without the JSON.stringify call.

If this fails try the following which will post form encoded information(the default) not json.
client side

```
$.post('../../Services/AjaxServices.svc/SaveUser',
 {"userId": userID, "userEmail": userEmail, "userName": userName}
);
```

server side

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "SaveUser?userId={userId}&userEmail={userEmail}&userName={userName}")]
public void SaveUser(string userId, string userEmail, string userName)
```

Comment: I updated the RequestFormat property and removed stringify; I then, however, received an internal server error and don't even make it inside the save method.

Comment: ok, I would also change the sig of SaveUser to contain string parameters to begin with, Have User user as a parameter means that you have no control over the conversion and will crash prior to your break point.

Comment: ok, I have altered my method signature to anticipate the 52 params individually. I have also added an 'alert' just before the ajax call to show what my object looks like prior to the call. the alert, "alert(JSON.stringify(dataJSON));" returns the expected {"UserID": userID...etc}
My method now anticipates the params (Guid userID, string userEmail...etc)
I am getting an internal server error prior to reaching the breakpoint inside the method, though.

Comment: Do you have any other service side methods that are called by ajax or is this the only one?, http 500 still seams to suggest it reaches your server

Comment: I have a 'GET' which is used to retrieve user information. It works perfectly, and in fact, I altered my 'POST' method at one point and made it GET as well to see if it would work, passing only a single param. It did work as GET, so I think the issue is specifically with POST, though I have no idea what it might be.

Comment: Mmm and what happens if you omit the processData parameter?

Comment: No effect, though I think that is redundant anyhow, as the default is set to true. In either case, it has been omitted but I am still returning internal server error

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening the Net tab in Firefox's Firebug and profiling your call to see what is the actual data being posted to the web-service? Try that, if the data in there is empty then you know there's something in your Javascript that's wrong, then try to debug your Javascript.

But the problem is probably that your web-service method signature is expecting a User object as a parameter but you are passing in a bunch of literal parameters. You can change your method signature to something like this and it might work:

```
public void SaveUser(string userID, string userEmail, string userName)
```

I read your comments, try this:

No stringify on your JSON object in client-side script

```
public class AjaxServices
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public void SaveUser(string userID, string userEmail, string userName)
    {
        //code here handles save
    }
}
```

Comment: I had previously tried to set the signature to expect only a userID, and passed only the id through the Ajax call. this, however, resulted in an internal server error, and my code never reached the breakpoint inside the save method.

Comment: @wblanks try changing your web-service method attribute `BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest` to `BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` , remove stringify as mentioned above and take in a couple of string parameters as i showed above to start with and keep the `RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json` attribute added

Comment: @wblanks for starters, make a copy of your current web-service call with 52 params and comment out the original. In the copied version just pass 1 parameter to test, make it `string userID` , then test trying to post to it just the 1 parameter from the client-side. See if this works, if it does, there might be something wrong with one of your 52 parameters, that will take additional debugging but might point you in the right direction.

Comment: @wblanks in other words, do a very simple test of the service call first with just 1 parameter (a string type parameter), once you get this working, you can expand your call to accept the rest of the parameters you need.

Comment: I sent one param in format {"UserID": UserID} to the method with a signature (Guid UserID). It returned an internal server error before reaching the breakpoint inside the method.

Comment: @wblanks don't use `Guid`, use a `string` to test, copy this exactly `public void SaveUser(string userID)` and see if it works with the 1 parameter

Answer (score 0):

Simply: the `data` attribute of `$.ajax()` is a map (object) of data not a string of data. Don't stringify the object before sending it:

```
var dataJSON = {"userID": userID, "userEmail": userEmail, "userName": userName};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../../Services/AjaxServices.svc/SaveUser',
    data: dataJSON,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json'
});
```